# Ubuntu not booting after removing linux partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I know it's stupid now, *after* I checked the internet, but I just formatted a partition that I had installed GRUB to.

Now, whenever I boot, I end up with ERROR 15 (which means "FILE NOT FOUND").

So, I got my Ubuntu 11.04 live disk out and installed it on top of the formatted partitition, and now at least I can boot - but I want to get rid of the duplicate Ubuntu now.

I think what I need to do is make GRUB look back on my first partition - which I have established to be /dev/sda1, or (hd0,0) in GRUB-talk. But, when trying

```
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
```

or trying:

```
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0,0)
```

I end up with:

```
Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... no
Checking if "/grub/stage1" exists... no

Error 15: File not found
```

Which is NOT good!

My `sudo fdisk -l` looks like this (run from the live installation):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ce6db

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       28210   226594816   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           29255       30402     9212929    5  Extended
/dev/sda3           28210       29255     8388608   83  Linux
/dev/sda5           29255       30402     9212928   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 7948 MB, 7948206080 bytes
245 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1021 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 15190 * 512 = 7777280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00077236

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        1021     7754464    b  W95 FAT32
```

(Note: sdb1 is my livedisk, an 8GB SD Card)

PS: The reason I'm going through all this is because I want to install Android-x86, but the GRUB it comes with wont recognize Ubuntu, so it's not much of a dual-boot.

Comment: Dif you formatted the partition where there were only grub or the whole Ubuntu?

Comment: The partition I formatted had GRUB installed, and it was Android-x86. I think my GRUB is installed to the MBR, because as mentioned there doesn't seem to be a `/boot/grub/stage1` inside my main Ubuntu partition. So, effectively, there was only GRUB on that partition. My Ubuntu is, thankfully safe.

Comment: I should probably mention that I *can* boot into my main Ubuntu - though only through the Ubuntu I installed from my livedisk 30 mins ago. That's not what I want, as it takes up disk space, and time when booting up (it means I have to watch the screen util GRUB is up then use the arrow keys to select the main Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you can boot into your old Ubuntu. If that is the case, it should be fairly easy to fix this. Open a handy terminal and try this on the main Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --recheck
```

As for getting Android to work, you might be able to install it without a bootloader. Then boot into the main Ubuntu and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if that finds it.

Answer (score 0):

*I believe this is adaptable for use on any Ubuntu distribution to dual boot with Android X86 without having to use separate partitions for each OS. This works thanks to the ability to use the same ext4 journaling file system for both operating systems. It took me a couple days to compile this. If your Ubuntu or Android X86 distribution are different, simply remember to make the appropriate terminal command changes (Android X86 4.4 to 5.1 would look like; `initrd /android-4.4-r3/initrd.img}` to `initrd /android-5.1-r1/initrd.img}`). Check system for 64 bit support before downloading .ISO files. If your system does not support 64 bit, use 32 bit, or 86 bit.*

---

**How to install dual boot of Android 4.4 x86 r3 and Ubuntu (on the same partition)**

### *(Works with other revisions and versions of Android X86)*

Things you will need:

- Non-partitioned HDD (formatted)
- (x2) USB flash drives 2GB or larger
- Secondary PC to flash .ISO files to USB flash drives

Begin by downloading Unetbootin, and .ISO files for both Android x86, and Ubuntu.

Flash the .ISO files to each of the USB flash drives.

Enter BIOS on PC with formatted HDD and enable booting from USB/CD.

Reboot PC with USB flash drive inserted containing Ubuntu .ISO and complete a full install.

Reboot PC with USB flash drive inserted containing Android x86 4.4 r3 and begin install following these exceptions:

- When prompted, select HDD sda1 and DO NOT format or select another file system.
- When prompted, DO NOT install GRUB, or EFI GRUB 2.
- When prompted, select as read and write.

Remove all media and boot the PC (it will automatically load Ubuntu).

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Using the arrow keys, navigate the the line below the last current entry in the custom boot loader menu and make the following four entries:

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,1)'
linux /android-4.4-r3/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-4.4-r3
initrd /android-4.4-r3/initrd.img}
```

Press and hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, then press <kbd>y</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Immediately after BIOS loads, press and hold the Shift key until GRUB loads.

Select which operating system you wish to use.

---

**RECOMMENDED! Load Ubuntu first, and create a disk image (.ISO file) of your new dual boot set-up and flash it to another USB flash drive and store it as a backup. You can do this after you apply any updates, or install any programs you wish.**

---

The result should be a dual booted Ubuntu and Android X86 utilizing the default Ubuntu GRUB2 boot loader menu with the benefits of; no separate partition for OS's, shared Linux swap space, same file system (ext4), space for installation of Android applications limited ONLY to the space remaining on your HDD (not a weak 2Gb-??Gb partition), and the ability to file browse between Ubuntu and Android X86. Essentially you have installed Android X86 within Ubuntu.

note: *Unetbootin now has a self contained application downloadable and compatible with Windows.*